# jquery ajax parsing query

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have successfully retrieved some XML data using AJAX, but I only want to return the first result of the 3rd result. How would I go about this? My code is below. For example, I just want the first child result returned.

The second question is: How would I separate the second result in a separate `div`?

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'xml/gt.xml',
   dataType: 'xml',
   success: function (data) {
       $(data).find('ROWSET ROW').each(function () {
           var desc = $(this).find('merchant_category').text();

           $('.timeline .test').append(
               $('<p />', {
                   text: desc
               }) 
           );
       });
   },

   error: function () {
       $('.timeline').text('failed to get feed');

   }

});
```

Comment: would be helpful to include some sample xml so the person answering doesn't have to generate it themselves to demonstrate the answer

Comment: appologies my xml can be found here  http://anteatercycles.co.uk/xml_Anteater/xml/gt.xml

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit unsure whats your real problem. But if you want to put the next "Merchant Category" in a new  you simple need to add this within your

```
append($('<div>',{text:'<p>'+desc+'</p>'}));
```